# Continuous projection is open

Tags: general-topology, continuity, topological-vector-spaces, open-map

Let $E$ be topological vector space Hausdorff, and $p: E \longrightarrow E$ be a continuous projection of $E$, that is, $p$ is linear and $p^2=p$, where $p^2=p$ means
$$p(p(x))=p(x),\;\forall \; x \in E.$$
I want to prove that $p$ is open.

So, I think it's enough to prove that given $ x \in E $ then the set $ p(V) \in E$ is a neighborhood of $ p(x) \in E $, where $ V: = U_0 + x  \subset E$ is a neighborhood of $ x $, with $ U_0 $ a neighborhood of $ 0 \in E $.

Comment: A projection on a single point is continuous, but if the point is not a connected component, it is not open

Comment: @Exodd I think that there is something wrong with what you said, because what I put on it is a [Treves](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kClvQ1qk9r8C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) exercise. See Exercise 9.3, page 83.

Comment: Is $p$ supposed to be linear?

Comment: @Aweygan Yes. Linear.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the hypothesis that it is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $M=P(E)$.  It suffices to show that for any open neighborhood $U$ of $0\in E$, there is an open neighborhood $V\subset M$ of $0$ such that $V\subset P(U)$ (where the topology on $M$ is just the subspace topology).

Now fix an open neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in $E$, and let $V=U\cap M$.  Then $V$ is an open neighborhood of $0$ in $M$. If $x\in V$, then in particular $x$ is in $U$, and $Px=x$ (since $x\in M$), so $x\in P(U)$ and thus $V\subset P(U)$.

Comment: Does this mean, even if $P$ is not continuous, it is still an open map?

Comment: @user760 That's correct, continuity was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

$p$ may not be open.
For example, let $E$ be R$^n$.
For all $x \in E$, let $p(x) = 0$.
Thus $p^2 = p$.
Now $E$ is open but $p(E) = {0}$ is not open.Consequently $p$ is not open.

The definition you gave for a projection is unusual.

Comment: even though $ p $ is linear?

Comment: I think what is implicit in the question is that $p$ is open when the codomain is the range, with the subspace topology.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that $p$ has a closed image in $E$, as $E$ is Hausdorff. So $p[E]$ is not open unless it equals $E$, by connectedness.

So $p$ can only be open as a map $E \to p[E]$. This would follow if $E$ were a Banach space (open mapping theorem), but I'm not sure it holds for any Hausdorff TVS $E$.